# Puppet Server not starting up in Centos7

Tags: puppet

I have recently installed puppet5 in Centos7 (Running in VirtualBox). After installation I tried starting it which thrown the below message.
Is there anything should I do with configuration?

```
[root@puppet ~]# systemctl status puppetserver -l
● puppetserver.service - puppetserver Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/puppetserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Thu 2018-01-25 13:59:44 IST; 32s ago
  Control: 10284 (bash)
   CGroup: /system.slice/puppetserver.service
           ├─10284 bash /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/cli/apps/start
           ├─10291 java -Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.security.egd=/dev/urandom -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p -cp /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/puppet-server-release.jar:/opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/jruby-1_7.jar:/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/jars/* clojure.main -m puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.main --config /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/conf.d --bootstrap-config /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/services.d/,/opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/config/services.d/ --restart-file /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/restartcounter
           └─10366 sleep 1
Jan 25 13:59:44 puppet systemd[1]: Starting puppetserver Service...

Journal Logs:
Jan 25 14:01:29 puppet puppetserver[10419]: Background process 10426 exited before start had completed
Jan 25 14:01:29 puppet systemd[1]: puppetserver.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 25 14:01:29 puppet systemd[1]: Failed to start puppetserver Service.
-- Subject: Unit puppetserver.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit puppetserver.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the VM has insufficient memory to run the server.

Edit the file `/etc/default/puppetserver` and lower the values of

```
JAVA_ARGS=" -Xms2g -Xmx2g ...
```

to:

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g ...
```

The VM must have at least 1GB RAM configured with the edited settings.

Comment: This seems plausible, but is there something in the question that specifically indicates a memory issue as the source of the problem?

Comment: This java argument  "XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p" suggests the process to be killed if there isn't enough memory. So if the server cannot start, I guess that this would be the first troubleshooting step.

Comment: In other words, then, no, it's all a guess.  A reasonable guess, to be sure, but we expect formal answers to be based on fact, not speculation.  This ought to have been suggested as a comment.  And it is within your power to make it one.

Comment: Well, first I deleted the post because I don't like to get in arguments with strangers but then I thought about it and changed my mind as there is nothing wrong in my answer. According to your logic, I should state all the reasons a service is failing to start in centos. This is impossible...

Comment: No, according to my logic, the question as currently presented does not afford an answer at all.  Perhaps that would change if the OP presented more information, such as an excerpt from the system log not filtered through systemd.  In any event, the point never was "you should not suggest this", but rather "you should not present it *as an answer*".

Comment: I can't comment in the OP's question because I have reputation under 50. Though I thought that SO is a community to help people, apparently looks like  I am wrong...